# Is CKeditor safe for letting end-users submit content?

Tags: javascript, security, ckeditor

I am about to let some users publish articles on my site.

To make it easier for them, I was thinking of using a CKeditor, let them have links, images, formating, etc ...

However I was thinking of javascript. Can someone inject javascript or will CKeditor clean it up? Do I need my own filtering?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Content submitted by the user should always be checked, even if an application like CKeditor generates valid code. You can use [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org) for serverside sanitizing.

Comment: is there an equivalent to HTMLPurifier in Java?

Comment: HTMLPurifier works only with PHP. About the [latest version](http://htmlpurifier.org/download): "The current version of HTML Purifier is 4.2.0, released on 2010-09-15, and is compatible with PHP 5.0.5 and up"