# User friendly HTML text editors for django hardened for use by non-staff, registered users

Tags: html, django, security, wysiwyg, usability

I'm looking for a way for users to securely create HTML contents, with basic HTML editing functionality, that integrates HTML editing functionality with server side HTML sanitization and image/file uploads. The text editor has to be **very** easy to use, because the majority of the users are children; so Markdown, wiki formatting, and the likes are out of the picture, Wymeditor with its clunky plugins are also out. The site is written in django.

Most of the text plugins/cms/blog apps I have seen seems to assume that the users will be trusted staffs. And some CMS apps (e.g. django-cms) does not even allow you to easily let non-staff users to edit content.

How do I do this securely in django?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about "django" integration, but we've been using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) successfully under ASP.NET for years - very customisable, including all toolbar options and plugins (which are pretty easy to write if necessary as well).

And trust me, we have some real "users"!!

(I have no association with CKEditor, other than being a satisfied user)

Comment: Does it have some sort of server side sanitization?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, @Lie, although it's possible that a plugin might be available to make it "safe".  Our "users" are authorised into the particular area of the system that utilised the editor, so we don't need it

Comment: @Lie, I've just done a quick search and discovered [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876203/is-ckeditor-safe-for-letting-end-users-submit-content) which is pointing to [this sanitizing component you might be interested in](http://htmlpurifier.org/).  **EDIT**, it's a PHP component, if that makes any difference to you

Comment: the reason I want server side integration is that I  want to avoid misconfiguration issues where the text editor might allow certain tags which the server sanitization doesn't allow (bad usability) or the contrary side, the sanitization code allowing codes that the text editor would never produce (security issue). I believe this needs both text editor and sanitizer to be designed to work together from a single configuration.

Comment: Sorry @Lie, I'm afraid I can't really comment on that, as it's not something I have any experience with

Answer (score 1):

Just to show you can't please all the people all the time, my organization also uses CKEditor and we've had numerous problems with it. Most of those problems have been user-related, i.e. they're doing something wrong in the first place, but that seems to be the point of your question -- something even the most inept user can't break.

However, that said, we're still using it because I've yet to find anything out there much better. There's always TinyMCE, but that's as much, if not more of a headache itself. I was recently turned on to a new one (or at least new to me) called [RedactorJS](http://redactorjs.com/), that I'm starting to look into deploying. There's already a [Django package](https://github.com/TigorC/django-redactorjs) for it as well. Like I said, I haven't used it yet, so I can't attest to how it will end up working in practice, but it seems pretty slick.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that a lot of the issues with CKEditor seem to be browser-based as well, which depending on @freefaller's office setup may explain why he loves it and I don't. Originally, all users were still on IE7. We finally upgraded everyone to IE8, and that has helped some, but some new issues were introduced. We'd like to upgrade to IE9, but most of the staff is still on XP machines. I can say that I haven't noticed any issues with CKEditor with IE9, so if you're running IE9+, you may not have any issues with CKEditor. Gotta love enterprise, eh? ;)

Comment: I do not need advanced formatting like tables or most things that requires the style attributes, so that's a thing to consider. The most important thing for me is that the editor has a server side component that can sanitize the posted html without having separate configuration file for the sanitizer and the editor (because separate configuration is just opening a can of worms). I can do the integration work myself if needed be, although having a django integration would be a plus. I'm rather surprised that none of the online editors I've seen seem to have any server side sanitizing component.

Comment: unfortunately most schools in my area seems to run on IE8, most of our users are going to be school children. I'm starting to think about just giving them plain text editor instead, and just escape all htmls and do a simple paragraph splitting. But that's not really possible since they do need to use images and attach files.